# Numerical Analysis (Solving a nonlinear equation)?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have a non-linear equation 
$$-\sin(\eta)  \sin(\delta)  \sin(\theta) - \cos(\eta)  \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta) + \sin(\eta) \cos(\delta) \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi)-\cos(\rho)=0$$

Suppose we have four $\delta$, i.e.,$\delta_1$,$\delta_2$,$\delta_3$,$\delta_4$.So that we have four equations to slove the problem, with 3 unknowns,i.e., $\theta$,$\phi$,$\rho$. Let  $\eta$ is a known constant (we can use just 3 of the equations). I want to implement this on a hardware, so I can not solve  that by Newton-Raphson (because of the matrix inverse in the method). What are the other solutions?

Comment: So you have 4 equations? or 3? What do you mean by 'implement on a hardware'?

Comment: We have for equations, but we need just three of them, so you can suppose that we have 3 equations and 3 unknowns. By implement, I mean, it is a part of an algorithm in signal processing, and to have a system in real world, we need to do that on an electronic board. The electronic board, that we have, is not capable of taking the inverse of a matrix, so we need to use a simpler algorithm.

Comment: Before implementing it on a hardware I suggest you to see if this problem has a solution. Do you have access to python/R/mathematica/Matlab?

Comment: I have checked that in Matlab by Newton-Raphson, and I got the solution exactly. But, I am searching for a better solution for the hardware!

Comment: I see, I guess your hardware can perform basic arithmetic. You can invert a 3x3 matrix with simple operations

Comment: Did you see a method to do such a work? Matlab uses "SVD" to take the "More-Penrose pseudo inverse", so it is hard to break the operations into simple ones. Thanks for your discussion.

Comment: you can try with this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html